# How to add <%= %> tag in code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls, tags

I have a few Input Controls (text) created in the code-behind as part of dynamic RadiobuttonLists (so that a textbox sits next to each of the radiobutton):

```
RadioButtonList radioOption = new RadioButtonList();

radiobuttonlist.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt.Rows[i][9].ToString() + " <input id=\"" + name + "\" runat=\"server\" type=\"text\" value=\"Enter text\" />")
```

All the controls are within UpdatePanel.

How do I update the input tag in my code behind so I can get the value to be something like this:

```
value="<%= this.InputValue %>" />
```

The reason is so that I can access/set the values in the Page_Load (as on postback, the input text disappears):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
    { 
        this.InputValue = "something"; 
    } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: you can access the value directly in your code behind. No need to use <%= %>

Comment: I should update my question - the reason I'm doing this is because everytime on postback, the input text disappears. I am trying to bind the user input text to the input controls.

Answer (score 1):

The value is always disappearing because you are not persisting the data across post backs.  I don't even this

> "<%= this.InputValue %>"

Would render the way you think it would.  The <% %> tags are rendered by the server, not the browser.  Instead, use a viewstate or session to persist the value across post backs. If you need help with that, post more of your control's code and where you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running into issue with the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

When you dynamically add controls to the page's controls collection, you need to set them up at the right time.  From the above-linked documentation:

> Raised after the start stage is complete and before the initialization
>   stage begins.
>
> Use this event for the following:
>   ...
>
> - Create or re-create dynamic controls.
>
> ...

This way you can just use the normal ASP.NET view state to persist information across PostBacks.

If you create your dynamic RadioButtonLists during the [Page_PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx) event, I imagine most of your problems will be solved.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButtonList radioOption = new RadioButtonList();
    radiobuttonlist.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt.Rows[i][9].ToString() + " <input id=\"" + name + "\" runat=\"server\" type=\"text\" value=\"Enter text\" />")
}
```

Comment: Hi jadarnel - all the dynamic controls are created in the OnInit function and not Page_Load. All my user controls eg. table, radiobuttonlist, checkboxes have their values retained because of that, except for the input control (which is part of the radiobuttonlist)...thus my problem...any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `UpdatePanel.Update method` on your code behind, in order to update your content with the new value

Note : your field InputValue  mus be in section UpdatePanel, in order to refresh

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx

Comment: Hi Frederique, I am already using UpdatePanel to contain ALL my dynamic controls. All my user controls, e.g. tables, checkboxes, radiobuttonlists, textboxes have their value retained because of that. However, my input control (which is part of the radiobuttonlist) is the only control without value retained..thus my problem. Any ideas?